# Ошибка создания объекта класса fstream c++

Tags: c++, файлы, запись

```
std::fstream f1("start.txt", std::ios::in);
```

100 процентов ошибка в этой строчке кода. Выдает ошибку сборки :

1>libcpmtd.lib(xlocale.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf >::sgetc(void)" (?sgetc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHXZ) уже определен в msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(syserror.obj) : error LNK2038: обнаружено несоответствие для "RuntimeLibrary": значение "MTd_StaticDebug" не соответствует значению "MDd_DynamicDebug"

Comment: меняли параметр /MD / MT ? или используете библиотеку/длл с несоответствующими опциями

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, это решило проблему!